# How to implement geocoding responses using nodejs/javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps-api-3

I'm a newbie in google map api. I'm trying to implement the google maps geocoding api.
[Geocoding API on Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Geocoding)

```
exports.FindByKeyWord = function (req, res, next) {

    var API_KEY = "SOMEDATA";
    var BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

    var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";

    var url = BASE_URL + address + "&key=" + API_KEY;

    var map = new google.maps.Map();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    geocoder.geocode(url, function(results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });
            res.json(marker);
        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }
    });
};
```

I want to response json format, however my function throw an error

> google is not define

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the google maps api script correctly imported?

Comment: I think you're getting confused between the Geocoding API and the client-side JavaScript API. You're using the latter here, but that's designed to be run in a browser, not on a server, hence why you're getting an error. You need to make REST calls to the URL you've specified in `url` instead. Basically everything from `var map = new google.maps.Map();` onwards in your code will not work in Node.

Comment: You should import google library at the beginwitha require('google'); or similar statement.

Comment: @Oscar: There is no official Google Maps Node.js library, they won't be able to require it. The API he's trying to use is designed to be embedded with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: @JoeClay
I'm implementing server-side. I mean, how to have a response json data format to a text string.

Comment: @Ntlzz93: I'll write an answer, bear with me for a few minutes.

Comment: @Ntlzz93: Done! Let me know if you need any more pointers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you're getting confused between the Geocoding REST API and the client-side JavaScript API. You're using the latter here, but that's designed to be run in a browser, not on a server, hence why you're getting an error.

Using the REST API is pretty simple in this case - all you have to do is make a HTTP request to the URL you've already created in your example code, and then pass the result through to your server's response. I'd recommend using a library like [Request](https://github.com/request/request) or [SuperAgent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) to simplify this.

Here's an (untested) example, using Request:

```
// npm install request --save
var request = require("request");

exports.FindByKeyWord = function (req, res, next) {

    var API_KEY = "SOMEDATA";
    var BASE_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";

    var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA";

    var url = BASE_URL + address + "&key=" + API_KEY;

    request(url, function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            res.json(body);
        }
        else {
            // The request failed, handle it
        }
    });
};
```

Effectively, your server acts as a middleman between your users and the Google API - this can be really handy, as it means you can modify the request before it gets sent off to be geocoded, and allows you to do stuff like caching results (you only get 2,500 free requests a day on the REST API, so this is very important if you expect non-trivial amounts of traffic!).

Comment: @Ntlzz93: Glad I could help!